# How to change Tab Style and Color using AppCompat Library

Tags: android, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

I am making a small program in which i am using **Fragment Tabs with swipe**, to make it stylish i used **Style Generator**, and my experience was good with that.

Now i wanna do a small change in existing look of my Tabs, this time i am talking about **Tab Text style**.

first view screen shot of my **simple stylish ActionBar**

[image]

Like we can see all **Tab's text** are **looking equivalent**, so here i need your help, in my case text style for **selected** Tab will remain same **white as bold** as it is looking, but want to **change** text **style for others** as **normal** (i mean those are not selected like:- IOS and WINDOWS)

**styles.xml:**

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Compatstyle4" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_compatstyle4</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Compatstyle4</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Compatstyle4</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Compatstyle4</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Compatstyle4</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Compatstyle4</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_compatstyle4</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_compatstyle4</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Compatstyle4</item>

                <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
        <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Compatstyle4.Widget</item>

    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Compatstyle4" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_compatstyle4</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_compatstyle4</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_compatstyle4</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Compatstyle4</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Compatstyle4" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_compatstyle4</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Compatstyle4</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.Compatstyle4" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">    
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_compatstyle4</item>  
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.Compatstyle4" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_compatstyle4</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Compatstyle4" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_compatstyle4</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.Compatstyle4" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_compatstyle4</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_compatstyle4</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_compatstyle4</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar.Compatstyle4" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_compatstyle4</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Compatstyle4" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_compatstyle4</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Compatstyle4.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Compatstyle4</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Compatstyle4</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Like:**  I want to show text color as default for selected tab and gray for others

Answer (score 6):

You will need to do settings in three places.

1. Your ActionBAr theme, where I set my tabstyle as a custom one defined below.

   ```
   <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

   <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTabs</item>
   <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTabs_TextColor</item>
   ```
2. My custom tab style which refers to a drawable selector for various states.

   ```
   <!-- action bar tab styles -->
   <style name="CustomActionBarTabs" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_custom_actionbar_style</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#666666</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. My selector, set this as per your requirement.

   ```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <!-- Non focused states -->
   <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
   <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_custom_actionbar_style" />

     <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_custom_actionbar_style" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_custom_actionbar_style" />

   <!-- Pressed -->
   <!--    Non focused states -->
   <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_custom_actionbar_style" />
   <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_custom_actionbar_style" />

   <!--    Focused states -->
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_custom_actionbar_style" />
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_custom_actionbar_style" />
   </selector>
   ```

Comment: I tried the same, but the actionbar text color does not change.

Comment: Try
<item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTabs</item> with android: namespace

Comment: Yes that sloved my problem. I upvoted your answer btw.

Comment: Thanks. Glad to hear it worked. Btw, you can accept it too. :)

Comment: No I cannot I didn't asked that question ;-)

Comment: hehe, I have got old. Didnt notice that. ;-)

Comment: I am not being able to do this, I beg you, can you upload an example project with those appcompat tabs having a different color when selected and not selected?

Comment: @style/CustomActionBarTabs_TextColor is not defined in the answer.

Comment: Are you still using this? If yes I will update the answer else you can try the material way - http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_holo" />

<!-- Pressed -->
<!--    Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />

<!--    Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />
```

Comment: what if i want to show text color as default for selected tab and gray for others, i am placing my styles xml as well please see that !